# How do I enable slowmode via a command?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to enable slowmode via a command, in the form as `>slowmode <seconds>`, like `>slowmode 10`. My current code:

```
 @has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
 async def slowmode(ctx, amount):
    await ctx.channel.edit.slowmode.delay(int(amount))
```

and I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command slowmode:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dante\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dante\Desktop\Utilly\Utilly.py", line 116, in slowmode
    await ctx.channel.edit.slowmode.delay(int(amount))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'slowmode'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dante\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\dante\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dante\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'slowmode'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `discord.TextChannel.edit(slowmode_delay=amount)`

```py
@has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def slowmode(ctx, amount):
    try:
        await ctx.channel.edit(reason='Bot Slowmode Command', slowmode_delay=int(amount))
    except discord.Errors.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send('I do not have the permission to do this, please try again')
```